# Why are these headers not working in Android WebView?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-webview

So I'm setting up a WebView to show a partners website.  If the user does not have the feature set up. it will redirect them to our website,  since they are logged in on the device I need to pass our Authentication token in the request headers and our website will automatically log them.

It works on iOs but I can't get it to work on Android.  I'm intercepting the redirect and if it is to our website I am adding the auth header.  But it is not logging the user into the site.  It just shows our login page. The code is bellow.

```
webView?.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
    override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, url: String?): Boolean {
        if(!url!!.contains("ourwebsite.com/authenticate"))
            return false
        val am: AccountManager = AccountManager.get(context)
        val token = am.getPassword(Application.getAccount())
        val extraHeaders: MutableMap<String, String> = mutableMapOf()
        extraHeaders.put(AUTH_KEY, token)

        view?.loadUrl(url, extraHeaders)
        return false

    }
```

Comment: Why do you always return `false`?

Comment: @Naetmul because the documentation warns that if  there is a subframe with a non-http url on the website it would fail.  

I've tried it returning both true and false and there is no difference in the visible behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So our server folks were kind enough to add some logs for me and I saw this in the recorded headers

```
"auth-header": "some token",
```

When I'm adding the auth header in I'm adding with capitalization (because that is what is required by the server:

```
"Auth-Header"
```

Apparently the `rom RFC 2616 - "Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1", Section 4.2, "Message Headers":` states that headers are not case sensitive.  :(

So our servers need to handle the all lowercase protocol.